# Vue.js Conditional and V-For not working as intended

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, conditional-statements, v-for

Due to the [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function, only the first `v-if` is triggered even if the second one is the correct condition. When I console.log the `photos` object the number length of the 'photos' object gets smaller by increments of `4` until it's `0` hence why the first condition is hit. How do I stop this from happening to display the proper div ? Here is the body of my code **:**

```
<div v-if="(checkCount = 1)">
            <Splide :options="{ rewind: true }" aria-label="Carousel Pictures">
                <SplideSlide class="fs-800">
                    <div v-for="item in photos.splice(0, 4)" :key="item.id">
                        <a href="">
                            <img :src="item.img" alt="" />
                            <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </SplideSlide>
            </Splide>
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="(checkCount = 2)">
            <Splide :options="{ rewind: true }" aria-label="Carousel Pictures">
                <SplideSlide class="fs-800">
                    <div v-for="item in photos.splice(0, 4)" :key="item.id">
                        <a href="">
                            <img :src="item.img" alt="" />
                            <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide class="fs-800">
                    <div v-for="item in photos.splice(0, 4)" :key="item.id">
                        <a href="">
                            <img :src="item.img" alt="" />
                            <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </SplideSlide>
            </Splide>
        </div>
```

Here is the data and condition:

```
data() {
        return {
            photos: [
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 1,
                },
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 2,
                },
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 3,
                },
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 4,
                },
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 5,
                },
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 6,
                },
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 7,
                },
                {
                    img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
                    text: 8,
                },
            ],
        };
    },
    computed: {
        checkCount() {
            if (this.photos.length <= 4) {
                return 1;
            } else if (this.photos.length > 5 && this.photos.length <= 8) {
                return 2;
            } else if (this.photos.length > 9 && this.photos.length <= 12) {
                return 3;
            } else {
                return 4;
            }
        },
    },
```

Comment: Aside from what @Rob pointed out, `splice` removes elements, instead use `slice`, that returns a new array with the specified indexes

Answer (score 6):

This looks like an assigment not comparition:

`checkCount = 1`

try this instead:

`checkCount == 1` or `checkCount === 1`

Comment: Hello! I tried that and sadly the entire div no longer shows

Answer (score 1):

***Observations :***

- You are using assignment operator `=`, It should be comparison operator `==` or `===`.
- There is no property named as id in the item. I think it should be `item.text` instead of `item.id` as per your photos object.

***Explanantion :***

As per your current code, `checkCount` computed property will get the value based on the photos array length which is `8`. Hence, as per the second condition, computed property will return `2`.

But as you are splicing the photos array `photos.splice(0, 4)` inside the div. It will remove the 5 objects (`from index 0 to index 4`) from a photos array. Hence, In that case remaining objects will be only 3 and photos array length become `3` which trigger the computed property and will return `1`. That's the reason at the end you will be only see the first condition div content.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    photos: [
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 1,
      },
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 2,
      },
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 3,
      },
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 4,
      },
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 5,
      },
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 6,
      },
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 7,
      },
      {
        img: "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        text: 8,
      },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    checkCount() {
      if (this.photos.length <= 4) {
        return 1;
      } else if (this.photos.length > 5 && this.photos.length <= 8) {
        return 2;
      } else if (this.photos.length > 9 && this.photos.length <= 12) {
        return 3;
      } else {
        return 4;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="checkCount === 1">
    First Div
  </div>
  <div v-if="checkCount === 2">
    Second Div
    <div v-for="item in photos.splice(0, 4)" :key="item.text">
      <p>{{ item.text }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```